# Reading and writing to files simultaneously?

Tags: c++, file, file-io

Moved the question here. Suppose, I want to store 1,000,000,000 integers and cannot use my memory. I would use a file(which can easily handle so much data ).
How can I let it read and write and the same time.
Using `fstream file("file.txt', ios::out | ios::in );` doesn't create a file, in the first place. But supposing the file exists, I am unable to use to do reading and writing simultaneously.
WHat I mean is this :
Let the contents of the file be `111111`
Then if I run : -

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  fstream file("file.txt",ios:in|ios::out);
  char x;
  while( file>>x)
  {
    file<<'0';
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the file's contents now be `101010` ? Read one character and then overwrite the next one with 0 ? Or incase the entire contents were read at once into some buffer, should there not be atleast one 0 in the file ? `1111110` ?
But the contents remain unaltered. Please explain.
Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question. When I put `file.tellg(); file.tellp();` before and after `file << '0';`, I do indeed get `101010` (discovered accidentally with debug output). This suggests some undefined behavior in the program? Bug in fstream implementation?

Answer (score 4):

The filestreams maintain two pointers, one of reading and one for writing. If you are doing read/write operations you need to set these pointers explicitly with the `seeg` and `seekp` member functions. You will also find that doing formatted I/O may interfere with what you are trying to do, so you should be using the `get`/`put` and `read`/`write` member functions instead.

See also [Why can't I read and append with std::fstream on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305480/why-cant-i-read-and-append-with-stdfstream-on-mac-os-x) for more on open modes with fstreams.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions which would be much more efficient: (i) use a 64-bit OS or (ii) use `mmap`.

[% man mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)